# Can an alchemist create extracts with metamagic feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, alchemist, metamagic

Potions can be created with metamagic feats, so long as they don't exceed the potion spell level limit (3).

> Magic Items and Metamagic Spells: With the right item creation feat, you can store a metamagic version of a spell in a scroll, potion, or wand. Level limits for potions and wands apply to the spell's higher spell level (after the application of the metamagic feat). A character doesn't need the metamagic feat to activate an item storing a metamagic version of a spell.

Can an alchemist apply metamagic feats that he knows to an extract as he creates it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### RAW: No

In short - extracts are not spells. An alchemist does not have "spells", despite the many similarities extracts have to spells. The RAW answer is a no.

Note that the alchemist's extracts are also not potions.  So although metamagic could be applied to potions, that isn't meaningful here.

### From the Creative Team: No

If that answer doesn't satisfy you, consider that James Jacobs (Creative Director) answered this question in a "ask me anything" on the Paizo forums:

> Danny Kesler: Can [an alchemist] select and benefit from metamagic feats? What about metamagic rods?
>
> James Jacobs: No.

[Source](http://Can%20he%20select%20and%20benefit%20from%20metamagic%20feats?%20What%20about%20metamagic%20rods?).